# How to import history in Dynamics?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

We currently have a system that have contacts in it. It will be mapped to the contact entity in Dynamics. Each of the contacts have an address history (Yes, some of them moved in the last 20 years).

We are soon to import the old system in Dynamics, and I am wondering how can I import a contact address history. Let assume I have user 'John' :

```
| Name | Address    | LivedThereFrom | LivedThereTo |
-----------------------------------------------------
| John | 123 X road | 2005           | 2008         |
| John | 123 Y road | 2008           | 2010         |
| John | 123 Z road | 2010           |              |  ==> Current address
```

So I will import 'John', then (with audit activated on addresses) import his address from 2005 to 2008, then update it's adresse to '123 Y road', then finally update it to '123 Z road' to have the full history available in Audit.

The problem is the following : How can I 'tag' those adresse from 2005 to 2008, 2008 to 2010 and then 'current'... I thought of using the 'created_on' field in the Audit table to help me, but there seems to be no way to modify that data (except going directly in the database and lose Microsoft's support on the product).

Thanks

Comment: "except going directly in the database and lose Microsoft's support on the product" ... oh, that can't be such a bad thing, can it? :) Besides, direct database manipulation is so...thrilling.

Comment: I explained the same thing to my client, but he won't listen. Life is too short ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client insists on through the product, then then another option is to import the addresses multiple times.

**Setup**

a) Turn on Auditing for the entity.

b) Add a new field to store the Date in which the Address was first used (Address Commencement Date)

**Import**

a) Import all Customer's oldest addresses first, set the Address Commenecement Date to the LivedThereFrom date

b) Export the addresses and make it available for re-importing.

c) Update the valyues in the spreadsheets based on the next available LivedThereFrom for that Customer.  Hint:  Convert the exported spreadsheet to XLSX first. Use formulas to work out which ones to replace.(e.g. VLOOKUP)   If really large spreadsheet then may need to split to enable re-importing under 5MB limit.  Could use ROW_NUMBER function in SQL to get a list of next addresses to update from your source system.

d) Continue doing c) until all records are loaded

In the Audit history you will see the the date which the new Address became active with the Address Commencement Date.

If they don't mind the direct database approach I'd go straight for the audit tables

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. We planned to do something like this following @jamnap answer/comment, but that's a really nice wrap up of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

One way that doesn't involve changing the way Dynamics handles contact addresses or doing any unsupported stuff is to make a custom entity the job of which is to store all of your contact's address history. It could contain the address, the dates between which that contact lived there, and (importantly) an N:1 or N:N relationship between your new address entity (say `new_Address`) and the `Contact` entity that links the two together.

A drawback is once this is done, you probably would have to introduce some business logic to sync the contact's address records to this new entity, which is certainly possible within Dynamics, and perhaps at some level, unavoidable.

Comment: Yeah, we thought about adding custom fields, but that's a hell of a job to do on all entities in dynamics. I wrote about addresses, but we would have to do the same for every entities (even contacts, let's say they got married and changed their name).

Comment: @DominicGoulet I suppose another way to go would be to create two custom date fields for each entity for which you want the history, import the first instance of each record, and then update each entity record, along with the original update dates, each time there was an update in your original system, which should trigger the auditing and create your history.

Comment: That could do it. Long job to do, but I don't see another solution. Thanks!